# php get only part of array in every minute

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get only part of an array in every minute regularly as every minute 10 array?

For example, in:

> First minute getting: 1 to 10
>  The second minute getting: 11 to 20
>   
>  Three minutes minute: 21 to 30 array 
>  Four minutes: 31 to 40
>   array 
>  up to the end full aryeh number is 313....

I tried to like this:

```
$tim = date('i');
$first = $tim + 9;
$end = $first * 2;
//This array is small:
$woides = '["2254365","2255017","2254288","2220745","2254452","2255239","2232426","2255143","2248513","2254295","2233629","2238651","2254901","2238430","2239471","2255294","2217888","2242302","2242310","2220380","56121236","2255244","2235716","2246897","2246737","2254887","2247978","2239897","2241012","2254335","2220237","2255028","2235095","2227798","2239447","2254980","2255007","2220163","2254340","2254572","2239514","2255272","2254465","2235742","2254835","2255162","2248951","2255162","2226917","2227166","2226813","2232705","2228886","2253837","2239974","2241068","2254978","2241496","2254777","2254277","2254714","2223700","2254538","2254929","2254463","2254730","2220651","2223937","2210917","2218965","2254774","2254616","2253001","2227270","2248955","2245845","2246022","2225224","2251945","56120984","2226503","2254339","2254457","2255184"]'; 
$input = json_decode($woides);
$output = array_slice($input, $first, $end);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

How can this be better and shorter?

Comment: You can ask for code reviews in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , it makes more sense to ask for review their

Comment: Ok, very nice.tnx

Answer (score 0):

Change the calculation of `$first`. Also `array_slice` takes length of array, not index of last item as the third argument:

```
$tim = date('i');
$first = $tim - ($tim % 10) + 1;
$arrayLength = 10;
//This array is small:
$woides = '["2254365","2255017","2254288","2220745","2254452","2255239","2232426","2255143","2248513","2254295","2233629","2238651","2254901","2238430","2239471","2255294","2217888","2242302","2242310","2220380","56121236","2255244","2235716","2246897","2246737","2254887","2247978","2239897","2241012","2254335","2220237","2255028","2235095","2227798","2239447","2254980","2255007","2220163","2254340","2254572","2239514","2255272","2254465","2235742","2254835","2255162","2248951","2255162","2226917","2227166","2226813","2232705","2228886","2253837","2239974","2241068","2254978","2241496","2254777","2254277","2254714","2223700","2254538","2254929","2254463","2254730","2220651","2223937","2210917","2218965","2254774","2254616","2253001","2227270","2248955","2245845","2246022","2225224","2251945","56120984","2226503","2254339","2254457","2255184"]'; 
$input = json_decode($woides);
$output = array_slice($input, $first, $arrayLength); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Your code don't work true. i want it for once pre (every) minute no every 10 minute. tnx